# PAC result block not invoked error iOS 11 (Beta 2)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cfnetwork

As part of iOS 11 Beta (2) testing activity we have upgraded an iPad. Post up gradation we are experiencing issue connecting to internet and the iPad is configured with **PAC file** (Worked fine till 10.3 version).

Tried running a web app and below is the error log and issue is some thing around PAC file. I have surfed through different blogs and couldn't find a solution. Can some one help me understand the issue and suggest a solution please? Appreciate your help, thanks in advance!

**Error log**:

```
2017-07-06 09:11:15.725037+0100 Web [274:6046]PAC result block not invoked
2017-07-06 09:11:15.726566+0100 Web [274:6046] [] nw_proxy_resolver_create_parsed_array PAC evaluation error: kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork: 308
```

Tried loading webpages in Safari and browser fails to load any webpage.

**Edit**:
Upgrading to iOS 11 Beta 3, Webpages are loading fine with PAC configured though pac error message is still logged.

Comment: Posting discussion link happening in Apple developer forum on this issue
 https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/81008

Also filed radar with apple